# How to change the view perspective in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, camera, rotation, perspective, viewpoint

I draw many lines to form a grid. I want to see the grid rotated on its X-axis, but I never get the intended result. I tried `glRotatef` and `gluLookAt` which does not work the way I want. Please see the pictures below.

[this is the grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKboQ.png)

[image]

[this is how I want to see it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fFJk.png)

[image]

Edit: geez, posting the code here is also hard, lol, anyway here it is.
Edit2: removed, only leave the code that has issues.

Please find the code below, no matter how I set the gluLookAt, the grid result won't be in the perspective I want.

```
#include <GL/glut.h>

void display() {

    ...

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    for (int i = 0; i < 720; i += 3)
    {   
        glColor3f(0, 1, 1);
        glVertex3f(linePoints[i], linePoints[i + 1], linePoints[i + 2]);
    }
    glEnd();

    glFlush();
}
void init() {

    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(60.0, 4.0 / 3.0, 1, 40);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(0, -2, 1.25, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0);
}
```

Comment: Edit: the code will not fit here

Answer (score 1):

Lets assume, that you have a grid in the xy plane of the world:

```cpp
glColor3f(0, 1, 1);
glBegin(GL_LINES);
for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i ++)
{   
    // horizontal
    glVertex3f(-50.0f + i*10.0f, -50.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f(-50.0f + i*10.0f,  50.0f, 0.0f);

    // vertical
    glVertex3f(-50.0f, -50.0f + i*10.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f( 50.0f, -50.0f + i*10.0f, 0.0f);
}
glEnd();
```

Ensure that the distance of to the far plane of the projection is large enough (see [`gluPerspective`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/gluPerspective.xml)). All the geometry which is not in between the near an far plane of the [Viewing frustum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viewing_frustum) is clipped.
Further more ensure that the aspect ratio (4.0 / 3.0) match the ratio of the viewport rectangle (window).

```cpp
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
gluPerspective(60.0, 4.0 / 3.0, 1, 200);
```

For the use of [`gluLookAt`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/gluLookAt.xml), the up vector of the view has to be [perpendicular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perpendicular) to the grid. If the grid is arranged parallel to the xy plane, then the up vector is z axis (0, 0, 1).
The target (center) is the center of the grid (0, 0, 0).
The point of view (eye position) is ought to be above and in front of the grid, for instance (0, -55, 50). Note the point of view is used for a grid with the bottom left of (-50, -50, 0) and a top right of (50, 50, 0).

```cpp
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
gluLookAt(0, -55.0, 50.0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I tried again with modification and it works. I also understand about gluPerspective and gluLookAt better now.